# Python About LearnPythonTheHardWay Exercise 3

Tags: python

So I've been going through [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) and am currently at [exercise 3](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex3.html).

The way I understand it, when I type in statements like `print "I will now count my chickens:"` and `print "Hens", 25 + 30 / 6`, I should see equivalent output `"I will now count my chickens and Hens 30 "` in my Terminal.

This does not seem to be the case, anyone knows why and how to resolve this?

Comment: to answer your question it would be interesting if not necessary to know what you actually see in your terminal

Comment: I use a texteditor called TextWrangler. When I type in print "I will no count my chickens:" in TextWrangler, nothing comes out in the Terminal.

Comment: Where do you save your python file and how do you execute it

Comment: When I tried to click "run in terminal" it says the file doesnt appear to contain a valid shebang line.

Comment: better not run it from textwrangler directly, rather open your terminal and do `python myfile.py` otherwise add `#!/usr/bin/python` as first line

Comment: @ChristianThieme to use the `hashbang` he has to be on a unix like os. Do you know if he is on one?

Comment: textwrangler is mac os x, so yes i know

Comment: @ChristianThieme Ah, okay, didn't know that. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a shebang header i.e. `#!/usr/bin/python3`  or whatever be the equivalent path for you. This tells the shell where to use your interpreter from for this script.

Then, save the text file.

Make it executable from the terminal (since you're on a Mac) by using `chmod +x filename.py`

Then, just execute the file as `./filename.py` from the terminal and you should see the desired output.